# Write the recursive function adjuster

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Write the recursive function adjuster. Given a list of type
x, an int and an element of type x, either remove from the front of the
list until it is the same length as int, or append to the end of the list
until it is the same length as the value specified by the int.

expected:

```
adjuster [1..10] (-2) 2 -> *** Exception: Invalid Size
adjuster [1..10] 0 2 -> []
adjuster "apple" 10 ’b’ -> "applebbbbb"
adjuster "apple" 5 ’b’ -> "apple"
adjuster "apple" 2 ’b’ -> "le"
adjuster [] 3 (7,4) -> [(7,4),(7,4),(7,4)]
```

What i did:

```
adjuster (x:xs) count b 
        | count < 0             = error "Invalid Size"
        | count == 0            = []
        | count < length xs     = adjuster xs (count-1) b
        | otherwise             = (adjuster xs (count-1) b):b
```

the error that I'm getting:

```
 * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
      Expected type: [t]
        Actual type: [[t]]
    * In the expression: (adjuster xs (count - 1) b) : b
      In an equation for `adjuster':
          adjuster (x : xs) count b
            | count < 0 = error "Invalid Size"
            | count == 0 = []
            | count < length xs = adjuster xs (count - 1) b
            | otherwise = (adjuster xs (count - 1) b) : b
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: [[t]] (bound at code01.hs:21:23)
        adjuster :: [a] -> Int -> [[t]] -> [t] (bound at code01.hs:21:1)
```

I'm new in haskell.I'll really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach, without error handling

```
adjuster xs n v = tnr n $ (++) (replicate n v) $ tnr n xs
      where tnr n r = take n $ reverse r
```

if you play with the signature, perhaps cleaner this way

```
adjuster n v = tnr . (++) (replicate n v) . tnr
             where tnr = take n . reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to construct a list within lists within lists and so on and so forth …

### Why is this?

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

The colon operator takes an element and a list of such elements as an argument and constructs a list from that (by prepending that element).

In your case if `(adjuster ...)` had type `[a]` then `b` must be of type `[[a]]`, by line 4 which is the same as the end result, but line 3 says the type is `[a]` - which is different. This is what GHC tries to tell you.

### How to fix it?

First of all, it is always a good advice to add a type signature to every top level function:

```
adjuster :: [a] -> Int -> a -> [a]
```

which should clean up your error-message and keep you honest, when implementing your function.

So how to fix this: - you could use `b:adjuster xs (count-1) b` but this would yield a result in the wrong order - so

choose a different operator: `(++)` and wrap the `b` inside a list.

```
    | otherwise             = (adjuster xs (count-1) b)++[b]
```

Now a few more hints:

- turn on `-Wall` when you compile your file - this will show you that you missed the case of `adjuster [] ..`.
- using `length` is a relatively expensive operation - as it needs to traverse the full list to be calculated.
- As an exercise - try to modify your function to not use `length` but only work with the base cases `[]` for list and `0` for `count` (here the function `replicate` might be helpful).